# XML issue copying filtered data along with nodes in a new parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

below is my input xml of which i want to produce my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class xmlns:xfa="soommmeee-tteexxxxtttttt">
    <students>
        <id>A</id>
        <name>jscvjab</name>
        <description>zcm,ab</description>
        <student>
            <id>1</id>
            <refObjectId>m9</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>25</id>
                <name>science</name>
                <firstname>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>kullu</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>nSVCm</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>zmbvc</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>2</id>
            <refObjectId>m5</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>92</id>
                <name>commerce</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Contents</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Slide</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Jerry</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>zxZXVj</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>kjsdgfjkvnwsa</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>kadbvscjkna</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <students>
        <id>B</id>
        <name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
        <description>mjZSVxcj</description>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>4</id>
            <refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>75</id>
                <name>PCM</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>j4423</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>sdbnfn</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>masdjkljk</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>msjkldbhfjkn</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <faculty>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Output</Type>
            <Key>Font</Key>
            <Value>10pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Out</Type>
            <Key>Text</Key>
            <Value>127,127,127</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>put</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>18pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>utp</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>127</Value>
        </configuration>
    </faculty>
    <Info />
    <Dean>
        <name>zcdfjkaqbkd</name>
    </Dean>
</class>
```

the xslt i am using is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="students">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:copy>
<Employee>
<xsl:for-each select="student">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="subject" mode="Employee" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
</Employee>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subject">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subject" mode="Employee">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()[not(self::lastname)]" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output so generated is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class xmlns:xfa="soommmeee-tteexxxxtttttt">
    <students>
        <id>A</id>
        <name>jscvjab</name>
        <description>zcm,ab</description>
        <student>
            <id>1</id>
            <refObjectId>m9</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>25</id>
                <name>science</name>
                <firstname>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>kullu</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>nSVCm</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>zmbvc</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>2</id>
            <refObjectId>m5</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>92</id>
                <name>commerce</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Contents</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Slide</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Jerry</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>zxZXVj</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>kjsdgfjkvnwsa</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>kadbvscjkna</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <Employee>
        <student>
            <subject>
                <id>25</id>
                <name>science</name>
                <firstname>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <subject>
                <id>92</id>
                <name>commerce</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Contents</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Slide</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Jerry</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </Employee>
    <students>
        <id>B</id>
        <name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
        <description>mjZSVxcj</description>
        <student>
            <id>3</id>
            <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <id>4</id>
            <refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
            <subject>
                <id>75</id>
                <name>PCM</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>j4423</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <Detail>
                        <lastNameDetail>
                            <fragId>sdbnfn</fragId>
                            <znjdvgsc>masdjkljk</znjdvgsc>
                            <zmdcb>msjkldbhfjkn</zmdcb>
                        </lastNameDetail>
                    </Detail>
                </lastname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </students>
    <Employee>
        <student>
            <subject>
                <id>91</id>
                <name>humanities</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m954</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Current</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>Title</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m9542</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>SubTitle</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Sr</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
            </subject>
        </student>
        <student>
            <subject>
                <id>75</id>
                <name>PCM</name>
                <firstname>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>j4423</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>Title</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <textContent>
                        <Id>m95</Id>
                        <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                        </title>
                        <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                            <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                        </text>
                        <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                    </textContent>
                    <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                </firstname>
            </subject>
        </student>
    </Employee>
    <faculty>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Output</Type>
            <Key>Font</Key>
            <Value>10pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>Out</Type>
            <Key>Text</Key>
            <Value>127,127,127</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>put</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>18pt</Value>
        </configuration>
        <configuration>
            <Type>utp</Type>
            <Key>Slide</Key>
            <Value>127</Value>
        </configuration>
    </faculty>
    <Info />
    <Dean>
        <name>zcdfjkaqbkd</name>
    </Dean>
    <Employee>
        <students>
            <id>A</id>
            <name>jscvjab</name>
            <description>zcm,ab</description>
            <student>
                <id>1</id>
                <refObjectId>m9</refObjectId>
                <subject>
                    <id>25</id>
                    <name>science</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
            <student>
                <id>2</id>
                <refObjectId>m5</refObjectId>
                <subject>
                    <id>92</id>
                    <name>commerce</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m9</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Contents</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>Slide</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m95</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>SubTitle</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Jerry</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
        </students>
        <Employee>
            <student>
                <subject>
                    <id>25</id>
                    <name>science</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
            <student>
                <subject>
                    <id>92</id>
                    <name>commerce</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m9</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Contents</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>Slide</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m95</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>SubTitle</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Jerry</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
        </Employee>
        <students>
            <id>B</id>
            <name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
            <description>mjZSVxcj</description>
            <student>
                <id>3</id>
                <refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
                <subject>
                    <id>91</id>
                    <name>humanities</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m954</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Current</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>Title</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m9542</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>SubTitle</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Sr</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
            <student>
                <id>4</id>
                <refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
                <subject>
                    <id>75</id>
                    <name>PCM</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>j4423</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m95</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
        </students>
        <Employee>
            <student>
                <subject>
                    <id>91</id>
                    <name>humanities</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m954</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Current</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>Title</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m9542</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>SubTitle</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Sr</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>SubTitle</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
            <student>
                <subject>
                    <id>75</id>
                    <name>PCM</name>
                    <firstname>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>j4423</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>Title</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <textContent>
                            <Id>m95</Id>
                            <title xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
                            </title>
                            <text xfa:contentType="text/html">
                                <body>sdjkhzjk</body>
                            </text>
                            <Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
                        </textContent>
                        <isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
                    </firstname>
                </subject>
            </student>
        </Employee>
    </Employee>
</class>
```

the desired output is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class xmlns:xfa="soommmeee-tteexxxxtttttt">
<students>
<id>A</id>
<name>jscvjab</name>
<description>zcm,ab</description>
<student>
<id>1</id>
<refObjectId>m9</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>25</id>
<name>science</name>
<firstname>
<isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
</firstname>
<lastname>
<Detail>
<lastNameDetail>
<fragId>kullu</fragId>
<znjdvgsc>nSVCm</znjdvgsc>
<zmdcb>zmbvc</zmdcb>
</lastNameDetail>
</Detail>
</lastname>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>2</id>
<refObjectId>m5</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>92</id>
<name>commerce</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>m9</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Contents</body>
</text>
<Key>Slide</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m95</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>SubTitle</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Jerry</body>
</text>
<Key>SubTitle</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
</firstname>
<lastname>
<Detail>
<lastNameDetail>
<fragId>zxZXVj</fragId>
<znjdvgsc>kjsdgfjkvnwsa</znjdvgsc>
<zmdcb>kadbvscjkna</zmdcb>
</lastNameDetail>
</Detail>
</lastname>
</subject>
</student>
</students>


<students>
<id>B</id>
<name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
<description>mjZSVxcj</description>
<student>
<id>3</id>
<refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>91</id>
<name>humanities</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>m954</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Current</body>
</text>
<Key>Title</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m9542</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>SubTitle</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Sr</body>
</text>
<Key>SubTitle</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
</firstname>
<lastname>
<Detail>
<lastNameDetail>
<fragId>aksbgdk</fragId>
<znjdvgsc>zsdbZXSBGCDSNXCJK</znjdvgsc>
<zmdcb>slzdhfksjfml</zmdcb>
</lastNameDetail>
</Detail>
</lastname>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>4</id>
<refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>75</id>
<name>PCM</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>j4423</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
</text>
<Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m95</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>sdjkhzjk</body>
</text>
<Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
</firstname>
<lastname>
<Detail>
<lastNameDetail>
<fragId>sdbnfn</fragId>
<znjdvgsc>masdjkljk</znjdvgsc>
<zmdcb>msjkldbhfjkn</zmdcb>
</lastNameDetail>
</Detail>
</lastname>
</subject>
</student>
</students>


<faculty>
<configuration>
<Type>Output</Type>
<Key>Font</Key>
<Value>10pt</Value>
</configuration>
<configuration>
<Type>Out</Type>
<Key>Text</Key>
<Value>127,127,127</Value>
</configuration>
<configuration>
<Type>put</Type>
<Key>Slide</Key>
<Value>18pt</Value>
</configuration>
<configuration>
<Type>utp</Type>
<Key>Slide</Key>
<Value>127</Value>
</configuration>
</faculty>
<Info />
<Dean>
<name>zcdfjkaqbkd</name>
</Dean>



<Employee>

<students>
<id>A</id>
<name>jscvjab</name>
<description>zcm,ab</description>
<student>
<id>1</id>
<refObjectId>m9</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>25</id>
<name>science</name>
<firstname>
<isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
</firstname>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>2</id>
<refObjectId>m5</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>92</id>
<name>commerce</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>m9</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Contents</body>
</text>
<Key>Slide</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m95</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>SubTitle</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Jerry</body>
</text>
<Key>SubTitle</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
</firstname>
</subject>
</student>
</students>


<students>
<id>B</id>
<name>jzvxcbhjnba</name>
<description>mjZSVxcj</description>
<student>
<id>3</id>
<refObjectId>m8</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>91</id>
<name>humanities</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>m954</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Current</body>
</text>
<Key>Title</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m9542</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>SubTitle</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Sr</body>
</text>
<Key>SubTitle</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>false</isDisplay>
</firstname>
</subject>
</student>
<student>
<id>4</id>
<refObjectId>m3</refObjectId>
<subject>
<id>75</id>
<name>PCM</name>
<firstname>
<textContent>
<Id>j4423</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>Title</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>dfzxsdbjchA</body>
</text>
<Key>zdbgcfjkbna</Key>
</textContent>
<textContent>
<Id>m95</Id>
<title xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>zdjbhfjkcda</body>
</title>
<text xfa:contentType="text/html">
<body>sdjkhzjk</body>
</text>
<Key>mzsdjkbjk</Key>
</textContent>
<isDisplay>true</isDisplay>
</firstname>
</subject>
</student>
</students>
</Employee>
</class>
```

please help......i am having this issue and not able to fix it from a long time....i tried from my last question but i did not found anyone who can fix it basically i want to create a new node called `Employee` in the exisiting xml and it should consist of all the data till the firstname node and then it should close all the data and after that all the nodes should be closed on their own but the problem i am facing is i am able to make the node `employe` but after every student node i need make it in the last of the xml and another issue i am facing is.....it is not displaying data, for `<students>` and `<student>` node, in the new `<Employee>` node so generated rest all is am getting as per my requirement.....pleasseeee helpppppp....i really need some help in this.....been so long i am working on it but unable to fix it....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with the XSLT taken from your previous question, is that it wasn't mentioned there are multiple `students` node. The XSLT is adding an `Employee` for each `Students` node, rather than just one.

It would help if you expressed your logic in a series of rules

1. Copy existing items as is
2. Append an `Employee` after the last child of `Class`
3. In the `Employee` copy existing `students`
4. Do not copy the `lastname` when copying the nodes under the new `Employee`

To get around this, have a template matching the parent `class` element, which then selects all the existing child nodes to copy, then adds the `Employee` element.

```
  <xsl:template match="class">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <Employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="students" mode="employee"/>
      </Employee>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

The `mode` here is used to indicate you are matching existing nodes in the a different way, to distinguish it from copying it from the existing `students` already copied. This means you will need a separate copy of the identity template to preserve the mode

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="employee"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

You then have a template, using this mode, to remove the last name

```
<xsl:template match="lastname" mode="employee" />
```

Try this XSLT, which does produce the same as your desired output (with indentation)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="employee">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="employee"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="class">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <Employee>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="students" mode="employee"/>
      </Employee>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lastname" mode="employee" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: working perfectly fine.....thanks for the help....really....a big thank you

Comment: and sorry for the inconvenience caused in the last question

Comment: No problem. If you have learned something about asking questions, that will help you in the future :)

Comment: one more thing....can we add <firstname> and not anything else on its own rather than removing <lastname> node manually....can we do that?

Comment: Yes, you can have a template matching "student" (`<xsl:template match="student" mode="employee" />`) where you then select only the child nodes you need.